# Too many acceptence Tests? Heap Allocation in Maven Junit Tests suddenly gets out of control

Tags: maven, junit, junit4, permgen, maven-surefire-plugin

Our Java Spring project has some acceptence tests that run with a **spring context** `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` that gets initialized once upon test execution and is kept alive for the entire cycle.

The **tests used to run fine** inside the project where the classes under test are located. We **added more and more tests** but then it **started to freeze up**. When this first happened, I moved the acceptence tests to their own project and it ran fine again. After adding more tests, it now freezes again, but not when reaching the old running amount of tests but much earlier.

Now, after maybe 30-40 tests, execution aborts with a `PermGen space error`. 
**Increasing Heap size will accomplish nothing**.

**VisualJvm** shows a sudden explosion of **heap allocation** from 1Gb to 2 just before it freezes.

This cannot be tracked down to a single test. I am assuming that too many objects are being kept in memory but I cannot be sure.

So I was wondering, if I could **split the execution of all tests into chunks** of maybe 20 tests. After each chunk, the spring context should be re-initialized and thus hopefully trigger garbage collection and free the heap.

I don't want to use **forkMode = always** with surefire to get a fresh context for EVERY test. This will work but slows down execution to an unacceptable length.

My only pointer so far is the use of **maven test groups** or **profiles** with the **surefire plugin**. I did manage to split the tests but obviously maven now runs only one of them during its test cycle, depending on which one I want.

However I don't want to explicitly specify a specific group to run but **run all of them, one after the other with a single build / command**.

Maybe that's not possible and I will have to set up our Jenkins with several builds that each run a profile / group / suite or execute a **batch script** to run them all after each other..? I would prefer an integrated version though, especially one that gets picked up by the eclipse JUnit runner, but I guess THAT's really too much to hope for..

Can anyone help?